# how to pass in params in web-inspector when debugging node

Tags: node.js, web-inspector

for example: `http://localhost:8989/debug?port=5858` would work but `http://localhost:8989/snooges/hello/debug?port=5858` would close the connection.

The code I would like to debug:

```
var express = require('express'); var app = express();

app.get('/stooges/:name?', function(req, res, next) { var name = req.params.name;
    switch ( name ? name.toLowerCase() : '' ) { case 'larry':
    case 'curly': case 'moe':
    res.send(name + ' is my favorite stooge.'); break;
    default: next();
} });
app.get('/stooges/*?', function(req, res){ res.send('no stooges listed');
});
app.get('/?', function(req, res){ res.send('hello world');
});
var port = 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```